# How to call a linux command from rspec file

Tags: ruby, linux, rspec

I am having a rspec ruby file named test_spec.rb . I want to add below command inside the file so to make it run when I run the rspec file.

```
exec("sudo gsutil cp test_object.txt gs://sample-bucket1")
```

But when I am running my code as soon as above command runs it stops the further execution. How can I prevent it.

Below is my Rspec code.

```
A=C.new

context "Bucket Resource : " do

#setup  data

before('The Original should create object') do

        #some code here 
        exec("sudo gsutil cp test_object.txt gs://sample-bucket1")
  end


#Positive Test cases

 describe "The Original should create object" do
      it  "Should execute successfully and return an instance " do
                 #define namevar
                 entity = "vivekkumarmishra17@gmail.com"
                 #define build params
                  build_params = {
                        entity: "user-vivekkumarmishra17@gmail.com",
                        role: "OWNER",
                  }
         expect(A.create_instance(build_params)).to be_an_instance_of(B)
        end
 end

after('The Original should create object') do
    #some code here
end
end
```

After running the above code, after hook is not called.

Comment: What actually happens when you run that linux command? Doe it fail silently or is there an error?

Comment: `exec` replaces your process with the given command, so it's actually the expected behavior. You might want to use [`\`...\``](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60) or [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) instead.

Comment: There is no error, it just stops executing. Actually I found other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use back tick for this inside your rspec file:

```
`sudo gsutil cp test_object.txt gs://sample-bucket1`
```